# how to access a column of a table via foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

I am new in SQL server and having trouble with this trigger code. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this line: `set NazivFirme=(select NazivFirme from inserted)`... This is where I get an error.

```
USE [BazaPreduzece]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[promenaNazivaFirme]    Script Date: 2017-03-28 5:29:47 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER trigger [dbo].[promenaNazivaFirme]
    on [dbo].[Firma]
    AFTER UPDATE
    as
    declare @FirmaID int
    select @FirmaID=FirmaID from inserted
    if update (NazivFirme)
    begin
    alter table Vlasnik disable trigger zabranaAzuriranjaNazivaFirme
    update [dbo].[Vlasnik]
    set NazivFirme=(select NazivFirme from inserted)
    where FirmaID=@FirmaID
    alter table Vlasnik enable trigger zabranaAzuriranjaNazivaFirme
    end
```

Comment: What is the error? You also have a serious problem with your logic, `inserted` will contain all the updated rows, not just one -- so that might be the problem you're facing.

Comment: this is the error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure promenaNazivaFirme, Line 18
Invalid column name 'NazivFirme'.

Comment: That we can't help you with without seeing what the table `Firma` looks like, but it sounds like it doesn't have a column called `NazivFirme`. But even if it had, your trigger would fail if you update more than 1 row.

Comment: Please specify the error you are getting, without that we can only guess. I also agree that it is NEVER a good idea to set a value of inserted to a scalar variable, but that typically does not cause an error but, far worse, data integrity problems.

Answer (score 0):

[That's theFirma and the Vlasnik tables...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6NIL.png)